# Laravel 4.2 Send email to user after post respond

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

so I have a ticket system, and what I want to do is when the user post a comment the other party should get an email, here is what I've accomplished so far:

In the CommentsController:

```
public function postComment($id) {
    $content = trim(Input::get('content'));
    if (empty($content)) {
        return Redirect::back();
    }
    if (Auth::user()->isAdmin() || $this->tickets->isTicketBelongsToUser(Auth::user()->id, $id)) {
        if (Input::hasFile('attachment')) {
            $attachmendId = Uploader::attach(Input::file('attachment'));
        }
        $comment = $this->comments->getNew(['content' => Input::get('content'), 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'attachment_id' => isset($attachmendId) ? $attachmendId : null, 'ticket_id' => $id]);        

    //START geting the user id and send email//     

    $client = $this->users->$id;
    $this->userMailer->CommentRespond($id); 

    //END geting the user id and send email//       

        $this->comments->save($comment);
    }
    return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Your comment has been sent');
}
```

In the UserMailer.php:

```
 public function CommentRespond(User $user)
    {
        $view    = 'emails.new-comment';
        $subject = 'New Comment has been posted';
        $data    = [
        'name' => $user->name
        ];
        return $this->sendTo($user->email, $subject, $view, $data);
    }
```

Error:

```
 ErrorException (E_NOTICE)

Undefined property: Care\Repositories\Eloquent\UsersRepository::$93
```

I know it there is something wrong with the variable assigning but I couldn't find it out, so please if you can help that will be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the culprit.

```
//START geting the user id and send email//     
//$client = $this->users->$id; <-- Wrong One
$client = $this->users->id;
$this->userMailer->CommentRespond($id);
```

I suggest you convert in to this.

UPDATE:
change the retrieval of user row to

```
$client = $this->users->getById($id);
$this->userMailer->CommentRespond($client);
```

then update CommentRespond

```
public function CommentRespond($user)
{
    $view    = 'emails.new-comment';
    $subject = 'New Comment has been posted';
    $data    = [
    'name' => $user['name']
    ];
    return $this->sendTo($user['email'], $subject, $view, $data);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replay but still getting error " Undefined property: Care\Repositories\Eloquent\UsersRepository::$id"

Comment: Updated above :)

Comment: well, still man I got an error " Undefined property: Care\Repositories\Eloquent\UsersRepository::$id"

Comment: the error in this line "   $client = $this->users->id;
"

Comment: then try to comment that line. since I dont see anywhere that you use $client

Comment: I've comment it but I got this new error: "Trying to get property of non-object
Line: "   'name' => $user->name  ""

Comment: Do you have a User model? If yes did you `use App\User;` above?

Comment: Yes it is there in the userMailer

Comment: Try to debug the result `dd($user)` and `dd($user->name)` if it is empty therefore the user doesnt exists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145935/discussion-between-kzy-and-rooot-999).

Comment: sir you were a great help, you've worked on my problem on the chat for more than hour and you solved the issue. Thank you very much sir

Comment: No problem, sorry it gotten that long i was working(office)/helping you :) Good luck in your app mate.